# PHPDoc to describe dynamic reference to static method

Tags: php, phpstorm, static-methods, phpdoc

```
    $class = 'MyClass';
    $class::method();
```

Is it possible to add auto-complete of `::method();` with PHPDoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But this way only:

```
<?php
$class = 'MyClass';
/** @var MyClass|string $class */
$class::method();
```

[image]